# Python - 'call' a class

Tags: python, function, class, call

If I have a class, is there anyway to catch the event of calling it as if it were a function?

```
obj = ExampleClass()
obj() -- and error occurs because I am 'calling' a class instance
```

I would like to handle this event inside the actual class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `__call__` method on your class.

```
class ExampleClass(object):
    def __call__(self):
        # do whatever you want here!
```